# gift registry looping program

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that makes entries in a gift registry. User can enter as many gift item desired and the store where this can be purchased. Once the user express desire to stop entering a new item, a summary of all the gift item & stores will be displayed.

These are my current codes:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GiftRegistry
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<GiftRegistry> list = new ArrayList<GiftRegistry>();
        private String item;
        private String store;
        char ans;

        System.out.print("Do you wish to make a gift registry? (y/n) ");
        ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while (ans != 'n') 
        {
            GiftRegistry object = new GiftRegistry();
                System.out.print("Enter item: ");
                object.setItem(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter store: ");
                object.setStore(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Any more items? (y/n) ");
                ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                list.add(object);
        }

         System.out.println("Gift Registry");
         for (GiftRegistry myObject : list) {
              System.out.print(myObject.getItem()+" - "+myObject.getStore());
              System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

this is the current input

```
Do you wish to make a gift registry? (y/n) y
Enter item: laptop
Enter store: Acer
Any more items? (y/n) y
Enter item: watch
Enter store: Swatch
Any more items? (y/n) n
```

It's supposed to make an output like this:

```
Gift Registry
laptop - Acer
watch - Swatch
```

Can someone please help me to have the correct output thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom object to hold your values -

```
class MyObject {
    private String item;
    private String Store;

    <getter & setters>

}
```

And add the user input data to a list.

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
...
while (ans != 'n') {
    MyObject object = new MyObject();
    System.out.print("Enter item: ");
    object.setItem(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter store: ");
    object.setStore(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Any more items? (y/n) ");
    ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    list.add(object);
}
```

And the correct way to print would be -

```
System.out.println("Gift Registry");
for (MyObject myObject : list) {
    System.out.print(myObject.getItem()+" - "+myObject.getStore());
    System.out.println();
}
```

And the Output will be -

```
Gift Registry
laptop - Acer
watch - Swatch
```

Comment: Kindly check my codes above. I tried to modified it with my terms. there are still 5 lines with errors

Answer (score 1):

well you will have to make a single string to store your item and store like this

```
String itemandStore=""
```

while (ans != 'n')
        {

```
    System.out.print("Enter item: ");
    itemandStore += input.nextLine() + " - ";

    System.out.print("Enter store: ");
    itemandStore += input.nextLine() + "\n";

    System.out.print("Any more items? (y/n) ");
    ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    }
System.out.println("Gift Registry\n" + item + store);
```

what happens in your code is

item contains "laptop - watch" appended in one object so the output is wrong.
If you still want to use different variables for items and stores i suggest this while printing

```
    String[] items=item.split("-");
    String[] stores=store.split("-");
     int i=0;
    while(items.length>i)
    {
    System.out.println(items[i] + " - " + stores[i]);
     i++;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a possible way to make it two variables instead of one? I know it may sound ridiculous for making it more complicated but pls help me :)

Comment: but the length of items is supposed to be indefinite. I dont get it :(

Comment: @DohaKik length would return the number of elements in an array

Comment: I have tried it but these lines   String[] items=item.split("-");
    String[] stores=store.split("-"); are errors

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more object oriented approach here and I would create a `Gift` class with this structure overriding the `toString` method to meet my expected output.

```
public class Gift{
  private String name;
  private String store;

//Getters & Setters

  public String toString(){
   return name + " " + store;
  }

}
```

Then I would create a `Collection` (a `List` would be appropiate) of Gift and add a new Gift to the list in the  `while (ans != 'n')` loop. To print the result I would loop the Gift List and print every Gift out:

```
for (Gift gift: myListofGifts){
  System.out.println(gift);
}
```